# Mathematica won't show imported excel spreadsheet data

Tags: import, spreadsheets

I have a problem with Mathematica 12.1 Student edition since every time i try to import data from excel with the command `Import["C:\\Users\\gpons\\OneDrive\\Escritorio\\prueba.xlsx"]` the output only shows the following: `import["C:\\Users\\gpons\\OneDrive\\Escritorio\\prueba.xlsx"]` unless i specify the sheet i want with `Import["C:\\Users\\gpons\\OneDrive\\Escritorio\\prueba.xlsx"][[1]]` and still, to get the the data i must select ***import*** from this menu:[image]  but what i get is the whole file instead of the first spreadsheet that i specified in the command with the spreadsheets indicated with double  ***{ }*** at the beginning and the end of each one.

What can i do to get the whole data with the first command i specified and the spreadsheet i want whenever i write `[[x]]` after this command, being x the number of spreadsheet inside the file? since from what i have researched everybody can execute this simple commands with no problem at all.

Comment: You have a problem in your code, you write "import" instead of "Import" (look a the capital letter).

Comment: Defined keywords/commands/variables appear in black, not in blue as shown.  The blue is supposed to be a helpful hint as to which symbols have definitions and which do not.